# Sending video attachment using gmail smtp server using python flask

Tags: python, flask, smtp, gmail, email-attachments

Hi I am trying to send video attachment to gmail using python flask.Unfortunately, my video attachment is empty(0Kb) when i send it out as an email. Before it was even sent out as a video attachment,the video is able to run.There is no error in my code before or after sending it as a video attachment in gmail

This is my code:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders



def send_email(subject, message, to_email, email_attachment_path=None):
    from_email = "abc@gmail.com"
    password = "abcdefghijklmnop"

    # create message object instance
    msg = MIMEMultipart()

    # setup the parameters of the message
    msg['From'] = 'abc@gmail.com'
    msg['To'] = 'def@gmail.com'
    msg['Subject'] = 'pigoen'

    # add in the message body
    msg.attach(MIMEText(message, 'plain'))

    # add attachment if provided
    if email_attachment_path is not None:
        # open the file in bynary
        attachment = open(email_attachment_path, "rb")

        # instance of MIMEBase and named as part
        part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        
        part.set_payload((attachment).read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)
        part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % email_attachment_path)
        # part.add_header('Content-Disposition',
        #                 'attachment; filename={}'.format("test.mp4"))
        # attach the instance 'part' to instance 'msg'
        msg.attach(part)

    # create SMTP session
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()

    # Login
    server.login(from_email, password)

    # send the message via the server.
    server.sendmail(from_email, to_email, msg.as_string())

    # Terminate the SMTP session and close the connection
    server.quit()
```

Another part of the code where i call the function above :

```
for i in range(len(boxes)):
            if i in indexes:
                x, y, w, h = boxes[i]
                label = "{}: {:.2f}%".format(str(classes[class_ids[i]]), confs[i] * 100)
                color = class_colors[classes[class_ids[i]]] # set the color based on the class name

                cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), color, 1)
                cv2.putText(img, label, (x, y - 5), font, 0.3, color, 1)

                print("Detected object:", classes[class_ids[i]])
        #show sharp object detected no bounding box also show nonsharp object with green box

            if i in indexes and classes[class_ids[i]] in ["scissors", "knife", "fork"]:
                sharpObjectDetected = True
                break

        if sharpObjectDetected and out is None:
              filename = 'output_' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S') + '.avi'
              out = cv2.VideoWriter(filename, fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))
              cv2.putText(frame, 'Sharp Object Detected!', (50,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0,0,255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
              subject = "Sharp object detected"
              message = "Please check the attached video"
              to_email = "def@gmail.com"
              email_attachment_path = filename
              send_email(subject, message, to_email, email_attachment_path)
```

It'll be great if i receive some guidance. This is my first time sending gmail using python flask and i find it very cool and interesting!

Comment: As an aside, it looks like your `email` code was written for an older Python version. The `email` module in the standard library was overhauled in Python 3.6 to be more logical, versatile, and succinct; new code should target the (no longer very) new `EmailMessage` API. Probably throw away this code and start over with modern code from [the Python `email` examples documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)